# An application of Brouwer fixed point Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, calculus-of-variations, fixed-point-theorems, euclidean-domain

1. Let $\zeta:\mathbb{R}\to [0,+\infty)$ be a continuous non-negative function such that $\zeta(0)=0$ and $\tau\mapsto \zeta(\tau)\tau$ is a non-decreasing differentiable function whose derivative is bounded on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Let $\{\phi_{k}, \lambda_{k}\}_{k \in \Bbb N}$ be the the Dirichlet eigenpairs of the n Laplace operator on an open bounded set $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^N$, i.e.,  $\phi_k\in H_0^1(\Omega)$  and $-\Delta \phi_k= \lambda_k\phi_k$. Recall $\{\phi_k\}_{k}$ is an orthonormal basis in $L^2(\Omega)$.
3. **Question:** Let $\mathcal{V}_{k}= \operatorname{span}\{\phi_1,\dotsc, \phi_{k}\}$. According to page 5 Eq (3.3) of [Starovoitov - Boundary value problem for a global in time parabolic equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04058), the Brouwer fixed-point theorem implies the existence of a vector $v_k\in \mathcal{V}_k$ such that
   \begin{equation}\label{Star-3.3}
   \int_\Omega \nabla v_{k}\cdot \nabla \phi dx + \int_\Omega\zeta(v_k)v_k\phi dx=\int_\Omega f\phi dx\quad\text{for all}\quad\phi\in \mathcal{V}_{k}.
   \end{equation}

How can one justify this claim?

In fact, that $\phi_k\in L^\infty (\Omega)$ is the only important property needed from $\phi_k$. So that by assumption the function $\phi(v_k)v_k$ is  bounded.
Since we are in finite-dimensional space and $\int_\Omega \nabla \phi_{i}\cdot \nabla \phi_j dx=\lambda_i\delta_{ij}$, the above equation reduces into finding $v_k=(v_{k,1}\phi_1+ \dotsb+v_{k,k}\phi_k)$ satisfying
\begin{equation}\label{Star-3.v}
  \sum_{i=1}^k v_{k,i}\lambda_i + \zeta(v_k)v_k = f_k\quad\text{in} \quad \mathcal{V}_{k},
\end{equation}
where  $f_k=(f_{k,1}\phi_1+ \dotsb+f_{k,k}\phi_k)$ is the projection of $f$ on $\mathcal V_k$ and by abuse of notation, we write again $\zeta(v_k)v_k$ to represent its own projection on $\mathcal V_k$.

> **Recall Brouwer fixed-point theorem**: Every continuous function from a closed ball of a Euclidean space into itself has a fixed point.

Comment: There seem to be some typos in the Question 3 above. For example, $ v_k\in \mathcal{V}_k$ , that is $v_k$ is a vector yet we compute its gradient. Or, there is the definition of  $\zeta:\mathbb{R}\to [0,+\infty)$ yet we use its value on $v_k$.

Comment: @Salcio Compte the gradient and use the fact $\phi_k$ are eigenvector (see step 2) using the weak formulation... The gradient disappear an leave place to $\lambda_i's$.

Comment: The main problem is to find an operator F such that the equation under consideration is equivalent to find $v_k$ such that  $F(v_k)= v_k$ and on which one  can apply the Brouwer fixed-point theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First using Brouwer**

Let $w\in \mathcal{V}_k$, necessarily $\zeta(w)$ is a bounded function since $\phi_k $'s are also bounded. The Lax-Milgram lemma implies there is a unique function $\widehat{w}\in  \mathcal{V}_k$
such that
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega\nabla\widehat{w}\nabla\phi +\zeta(w)\widehat{w}\phi -f\psi dx=0\quad\text{for all}\quad\phi\in \mathcal{V}_{k}.
\end{align}

The Poincar'{e}--Friedrichs inequality yields
\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega|\nabla\widehat{w}|^2dx  + \int_\Omega \zeta(w )\widehat{w}^2\, d x\leq \|f\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\,\|\widehat{w}\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\leq  C\|f\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\, \|\widehat{w}\|_{H_0^1(\Omega )} 
\end{equation}

Thus, letting $R=C\,\|f\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$, since $\varphi\geq0 $ we obtain the following estimates
\begin{align}\label{eq:boundedmapT}
&\|\widehat{w}\|_{H_0^1(\Omega )}\leq R
\quad\text{ and }\quad
 \int_\Omega \zeta(w )\widehat{w}^2\,dx\leq R^2.
\end{align}
We let $ \mathcal{B}_R=\big\{ w\in \mathcal{V}_k: \|w\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)} \leq R\big\}$, be the closed ball in $\mathcal{V}_k$ of radius $R$ centered at the origin.  Clearly, the mapping $T:\mathcal{V}_k\to \mathcal{B}_R$ with $Tw=\widehat{w}$  is well defined.

It remains to prove that $T$ is a continuous mapping. Indeed, let
$\{w_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{V}_k$ with $w_n= \lambda_{1,n}\phi_1+\cdots+  \lambda_{k,n}\phi_k$ converging in $\mathcal{V}_k$ to a function $w= \lambda_1\phi_1+\cdots+  \lambda_k\phi_k$; i.e., $\lambda_{\ell,n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty } \lambda_\ell$, $\ell=1,2,\cdots,k$.
By continuity we have $ \varphi(w_n)\xrightarrow{n\to \infty}\varphi(w)$ almost everywhere. In addition, the convergence in $L^2(\Omega)$ also holds, since the continuity gives $\sup_{n\geq 0} \|\varphi(w_n) \|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} <\infty$ because $\sup_{n\geq 0}\|w_n\|_{L^\infty(\Omega) } <\infty$.

On the other side, in virtue of  the first estimate above the sequence
$\{Tw_n\}$ is bounded in finite dimensional space $\mathcal{V}_k$ and thus converges $\mathcal{V}_k$ up to a subsequence  to some $w_*\in \mathcal{V}_k$. Altogether, it follows that, for all  $\phi\in \mathcal{V}_k\subset L^\infty(\Omega)$
%
\begin{align*}
(f,\phi)= \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_\Omega\nabla\widehat{w}_n\nabla\phi  
+\zeta(w_n)\widehat{w}_n\phi dx=
\int_\Omega\nabla\widehat{w}\nabla\phi  +\zeta(w)w_* \phi. 
\end{align*}

The uniqueness of $\widehat{w}$ entails  $w_*=\widehat{w}=Tw$ and hence  the whole sequence $\{Tw_n\}$ converges in $Tw$ in $\mathcal V_k$, which gives the continuity of $T$.

Therefore, by the Brouwer fixed-point theorem,  $T$ has a fixed point $v_k\in \mathcal V_k$, i.e., $v_k=Tv_k$ which clearly satisfies  the announced relation.

**An alternative.**

The given problem is equivalent to the minimization problem
\begin{align}
 \mathcal{J}(v_k)=  \min_{v\in \mathcal{V}_k}  \mathcal{J}(v)\quad \text{with}\quad  \mathcal{J}(v):=  \frac12 \int_\Omega|\nabla v|^2 dx + \int_\Omega G(v)d x + \int_\Omega fvd x
 \end{align}
and we define the function $G(v)=  \int_0^v\zeta(\tau)\tau d \tau $.  Note that $G$ is non-negative since $\zeta(\tau)\geq 0$ and that $\mathcal J$ is continuous on $\mathcal V_k$. Using the Poincaré-Friedrichs inequality we find that $\mathcal{J}(v)\to \infty$, as $\|v\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \to \infty$ and $v\in \mathcal{V}_k$. Which implies the existence of a minimizer $v_k\in \mathcal{V}_k$ of \mathcal{J}, since we are in finite dimension space.

Comment: Looks good. Another approach would be to use monotone operator theory. Also, the finite-dimensional system can be set up as $g(x)=0$ with $g:\mathbb R^k\to \mathbb R^k$ by $g_i(x):= \int_\Omega \nabla v \nabla \phi_i + \zeta(v)v\phi_i-f\phi_i$ where $v:=\sum_jx_j\phi_j$. Then $g(x)^Tx\ge0$ for all $x$ with $\|x\|=R$ for some $R$, which implies the existence of $x$ with $g(x)=0$. Then one does not need Lax-Milgram.

Comment: @daw Thanks for this additional information. Please do you have any good reference on this monotone operator theory?  It tooks me long to reach the first part of my answer

Comment: Ruzicka 'Nichtlineare Funktionalanalysis' (German) or Roubicek 'Nonlinear pdes', these result for elliptic pde are quite folklore

Comment: I need the book byRoubicek Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations with Applications is very nice..